# Not able to login to 16.04

Tags: login

Upgraded from version 15 to 16.04. Tried

```
ls -lah
-rw-------
```

shows .xsession-errors
Another

```
-rw-------
```

shows .xsession-errors.old

Please help.

Comment: When you say "not able to login", can you specify what you mean? What is showing on the screen? Is it rejecting your password, is there just a black console, what text is on the screen?

Comment: Shows the same login screen prompting for a password. Im able to go into ctrl+alt+f1 screen and login there but not here. I'm not able to access the guest account too.

Comment: I had similar issues after upgrading to 16.04. Still cants login to either Gnome or Ubuntu (Unity) as lightdm always throws me back to login screen without displaying an error.  I installed XFCE and Cinnamon and on both i can now login ....which really makes me wondering. Not a solution but maybe worth a try. Please add some information what login maanger and desktop environment you are using.

Comment: Hey I'm using the default lightdm. I tried gdm too. It did not work. I tried uninstalling the graphics card. It worked. After logging in, reinstalling the graphics in additional drivers brought me back to the same problem after rebooting. I use nvidia gtx 960m graphics card. How do I install my graphics card now.